# How to cache dynamic data with laravel or more globally what must be the logic of dynamic caching

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I have an `app` that have `users` and these `users` related which each others in almost every section. E.g **A** user is friend with **B**. **A** and **B** can block each other or be blocked. **A** and **B** can send media to each other etc, A can set your **profile photo** privacy hidden. They see each other's informations according to their `privacy status`, `friendship status` or `block status` ,`media relationship` (profile photo, shared media etc..). According to their relationship, **`relationship data`** may always be change with any other's interaction. So it seems data is dynamic, must be kept as dynamic and must not be cached (in my opinion).

I'm using **laravel** `elequent model` to collect `data` from `DB` and i have complicated `queries` that fetch `user data` with `user infos`, `friends's` and `friendship informations` etc. Almost every query, i collect the data with one hit. So when any of `friend` or `friendship data` change for `user`. These `one hit collected data` will change, from single or more point(s) of `data`. So when `data` renew and i try to get the `cached data` from `cache driver`(`redis` or `..`) it will not be the updated real `data`.

I want to show example with picture and expand my question.

[image]

In example i (`UserApp`) have a `friend list` that contains `my friend's infos` with `diffrent views`. When any friend interact with me like (`block me`, `sent media` to me, `hide their profile photo to everyone`..) or when i interact with them (`block them`,`remove from friendship`, `sent media` etc..) the data and views are changing dynamically without refresh. But this page is `refreshable` and i dont want to run `query` for every `refresh`. In my `app` there are same kind of `pages` and if `app` have lot of `users` these `requests` will be more expensive i think. What must be the correct way to save my `app` from `query` burden. If you show me the path.. i can move forward. thanks in advance..

**Example of frienship query data**

```
[
    {
        "id": 44,
        "name": "Name1",
        "surname": "Surname2",
        "country": null,
        "town": null,
        "email": null,
        "phone": "5559933939",
        "photo": "/App/Users/Profile/ProfilePictures/1/User_1~Time_1510076458061.jpg",
        "profession": null,
        "dob": "2011-10-29",
        "gender": 1,
        "statusTitle": "my status title",
        "rank": 1,
        "isPremium": 0,
        "isAllowedNotifications": 1,
        "isAllowedSmsNotifications": 0,
        "profilePhotoPrivacyStatus": "2",
        "statusTitlePrivacyStatus": "1",
        "playerID": null,
        "userID": 29,
        "friendID": 1,
        "friendshipRequester": null,
        "friendshipStatus": 3,
        "isBlocked": 0,
        "isAllowedToTakeReturnMedia": 0,
        "isSilenced": 0,
        "isMediaActiveAndChangable": 1,
        "isSeen": 0,
        "isCalled": 0,
        "myStatusForFriend": 1,
        "isBlockedByFriend": 0,
        "fromMeVideoCount": 1,
        "toMeVideoCount": 0,
    },
    {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "Name2",
        "surname": "Surname2",
        "country": null,
        "town": null,
        "email": null,
        "phone": "5559933123",
        "photo": "/App/Users/Profile/ProfilePictures/2/User_2~Time_1511690217936.jpg",
        "profession": null,
        "dob": "1992-10-27",
        "gender": 2,
        "statusTitle": "Hey! lets suprise me..",
        "rank": 1,
        "isPremium": 0,
        "isAllowedNotifications": 1,
        "isAllowedSmsNotifications": 0,
        "profilePhotoPrivacyStatus": null,
        "statusTitlePrivacyStatus": null,
        "playerID": "asda9d-12asda-4bd6-a882-sgdfadasd",
        "userID": 29,
        "friendID": 2,
        "friendshipRequester": 2,
        "friendshipStatus": 3,
        "isBlocked": 0,
        "isAllowedToTakeReturnMedia": 1,
        "isSilenced": 0,
        "isMediaActiveAndChangable": 1,
        "isSeen": 0,
        "isCalled": 0,
        "myStatusForFriend": 3,
        "isBlockedByFriend": 0,
        "fromMeVideoCount": 21,
        "toMeVideoCount": 0,
```

Comment: That data is looks pretty dynamic ... There is going to be a lot of management of this cache data... either you tie it to the session or to the user you have to manage when it becomes dirty and when to clean it up... This is a good candidate for a spa type front end...

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before. My solution was to wipe the cache while writing the update.
E.g. User A sends data -> wipe user A's cached info -> write the data.
User B reads User A data -> cache gets filled in again from DB.